# Which wallets support spending partial amounts of btc from a cold storage address?

Tags: coldstorage, spending, mycelium-wallet

Which wallets let you spend partial amounts from your btc address from a cold storage address without the need to import / sweeping it? I know mycellium has the feature, but I'd like to know if there are others that can do this.

Comment: Although I expect you to know this already: But if you only partially sweep your cold storage (by using its own address to return some bitcoins), then it cannot any longer be considered a cold storage since the private key has been exposed. To answer your question it would be good to know on which platform you want to do it on?

Answer (score 1):

I have a "watch only address" of my cold storage in Electrum. In this watch only address I can see all tx, and as such also create tx. I just cannot sign it. So I create it, save it to USB stick, bring it to cold storage, sign it, and bring it back to deliver to the network. I would guess the same can also be done with core wallet.

Answer (score 0):

They all do. Just set your custom change address to the same sending address.

*Note: This is a bad idea from a linkability standpoint.*